# How to properly use Buffer.from?

Tags: node.js

My current code uses Buffer('username:password').toString('base64')

That resulted in deprecated warning which lead to this fix: https://nodejs.org/fr/docs/guides/buffer-constructor-deprecation/

However, after replacing buffer with buffer.from(), getting below error:
Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"]

Old code:

```
headers: { Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer(this.settings.NPS_USERNAME + ':' + this.settings.NPS_PASSWORD).toString('base64') },
```

New code

```
headers: { Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(this.settings.NPS_USERNAME + ':' + this.settings.NPS_PASSWORD, 'base64') },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `Buffer.from` indicates the *input* format of the first argument. You are telling `Buffer.from` to expect the input `USERNAME:PASSWORD` to be a base64-encoded string, but this is wrong: the input clearly is not base64-encoded (not least because it includes a colon, which not a valid base64 character).

Instead, you want to indicate how the input *is* encoded, possibly `utf8`, and then separately call `toString('base64')` as you do in your original code, to produce base64 *output*:

```
Buffer.from(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD, 'utf8').toString('base64')
```